# Good book about parenting teens?

Tags: parents, teen

I have an 8 years old who is showing signs of teenage hood and want to prepare myself for the time ahead. There are many titles out there 
but it's hard to find which are most helpful and updated. Any suggestions?

Comment: We don't do specific product recommendations, but as three times commented, it doesn't really matter which book you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overall I find that solid books on parenting any age past toddlers likely are all you need.  There is not a lot you specifically need for teen years that you don't also need at 8yrs old.

So I would recommend books like, "[How to Talk So Kids Will Listen](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0743525086)", "[Hold On To Your Kids](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001LOEFZU)", "[Beyond Discipline: From Compliance to Community](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416604723)", and maybe something like "[Parenting From The Inside Out](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HZ1E5BM)" if you have never read one like that type yet.

And do not forget to check with your library. Many books are available as ebooks through them for free, or by old fashioned check out, but you can get a lot of books through them that used to be hard to get and they can often have them sent over from other branches if they do not usually stock it.  There is so much great reading you can do, but you need not spend a ton of money to do that.